# trying to access array offset on value of type null (php 7.4, Laravel 7.10.3)

Tags: php, laravel, curl

[So everything looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EI4BI.png)

So I get the Error message that you can see in the title from a simple code snippet that I took from an API Guide. I tried to use PHP 7.3 that doesn´t change my problem either. I'm pretty new to PHP and laravel and I think there is an easy way to solve this but I can't find it. I'm using PHP 7.4. and Laravel 7.10.3. I would be truly thankful if someone could help me.

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['query']) && $_GET['query'] != '') {
  $url = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
  $query_fields = [
          'autoCorrect' => 'true',
          'pageNumber' => 1,
          'pageSize' => 10,
          'safeSearch' => 'false',
          'q' => $_GET['query']
  ];
  $curl = curl_init($url . '?' . http_build_query($query_fields));
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
          'X-RapidAPI-Host: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
          'X-RapidAPI-Key: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
  ]);
  $response = json_decode(curl_exec($curl), true);
  curl_close($curl);
  $news = $response['value'];
}
?>
```

Comment: Hi Pody, please provide a screenshot of what response you are getting and what field you need to access.

Comment: thanks, I added a picture to explain it better.

Comment: What does `dd($response)` gives?

Answer (score 0):

Trying to access array offset on value of type null means the **$response is null** and still you are trying to access ['value'] from it.

Let's start by adding logs to your curl.

```
// Get request info as an array
$info = curl_getinfo($curl);

$response = curl_exec($curl); // Notice* don't try to decode without sanitizing/checking the response
curl_close($curl);

// Log the actual response from the remote server
Log::info('Curl response: ' . $response); // Are you seeing *value* in the response. If yes, then do json_decode()
```

Keep me posted in the comments below and I'll update the answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for your help, i get the following ViewException
curl_exec(): supplied resource is not a valid cURL handle resource